# Why can't NSFileManager open file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsfilemanager

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL* url = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
NSString* directory = [url absoluteString];
NSLog(@"%@",directory);
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directory]) NSLog(@"error!!!");
```

Here's the log generated by the code above:

```
2012-04-03 15:45:02.298 TopPlaces[805:13303] file://localhost/Users/yzyoyosir/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/2D6EC144-CF85-4994-8904-8FF5F8407FED/Library/Caches/
2012-04-03 15:45:02.300 TopPlaces[805:13303] file://localhost/Users/yzyoyosir/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/2D6EC144-CF85-4994-8904-8FF5F8407FED/Library/Caches/
2012-04-03 15:45:02.301 TopPlaces[805:13303] error!!!
```

Why have I got an error here. I mean why the directory does not exist?

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant Sorry, but I don't know what to put in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fileExistsAtPath:` needs a path as argument but you're giving an URL as absoluteString.

Change

```
NSString* directory = [url absoluteString];
```

to

```
NSString* directory = [url path];
```